# Plot KM curve using survfit in R without strata

Tags: r, survival

I want to plot a KM curve and get median survival data from the `survfit()` object but I don't want to split by strata - I want to know the whole population.

```r
fit <- survfit(Surv(Time, Status) ~ Group, data = A)
```

eg. I don't want to have `~ Group`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You then fit a model of the intercept. I generated some example data to illustrate this.

```
library(survival)

df <- data.frame(Status=c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1), 
                 Time=c(30,10,15,30,3,1,14,30,28,30,20,30))

df$forKM <- with(df, Surv(Time, Status == 1))

fit <- survfit(forKM ~ 1, data = df)
plot(fit)
```

[image]

If you don't want to see the confidence interval in the plot, then you should specify: `conf.int=F`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```r
fit <- survfit(Surv(Time, Status) ~ 1, data = A)
```